# Fluctuating battery capacity in coconutBattery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I am a new MacBook user. I have a problem with my battery. When I tried to see its stats from coconutBattery, sometimes it said 6200/6667(93%) and sometimes it said 6560/6667(97%) to be the full charge capacity. My cycle count is only 241 right now.

I don't have a screenshot while it said 97% and I don't keep track history of it. But sometimes it does fluctuate back to 97%.
I've already tried a SMC reset too, and the problem is still the same.

What is happening with the fluctuation and how do I get an accurate battery info?

coconutBattery Screenshot with 93.5% capacity:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you share a screenshot from coconutBattery?

Comment: Hi, i've already add it. But i dont have screenshot when it said 97%. I've already tried SMC reset but nothing changed.

Comment: It is nothing to do with coconutBattery.  Nor is it anything to do with the OS either.  The battery reports the information to the OS if it asks.  You can see battery report info in macOS by running this command in terminal: `system_profiler SPPowerDataType`  In boot camp you could run this powershell command to get the same information :`powercfg /batteryreport`.  Both report whatever the battery says - no more, no less.  That is what coconutBattery reports.

Comment: (continued) so the good thing about coconutBattery is it stores details on whatever period you want and you can ignore the outliers and compare to others.

Comment: is it because of a faulty battery? if it kinda fluctuate like 94-97? 
i'll try to update a bit if i can get hold of it when the bactery is fluctuating again.